# Using pre constructed sqlite database inside iOS app

Tags: ios, objective-c, sqlite

I need to include a sqlite database in my app (pre-made) and make changes further into it as the app is used. So my question is, is there any way to include a pre populated sqlite DB in the app's working environment and then use the native sqlite framework to edit/update/delete data from it ?

Some tutorial references for this will be appreciated.

Comment: What stops you for running a search?

Comment: @ElTomato i already did. Not to waste time, can we get an answer ?

Comment: Show us what you have done so far, then.

Answer (score 1):

I was looking for something like this [Sqlite](http://www.appcoda.com/sqlite-database-ios-app-tutorial/). Although it isn't upto the mark as i needed a tool or something for easily creating a large DB which i could later embed in my app. But still this tutorial does clear away some confusion.

P.S. there is a tool which you can use to view your DB. I don't believe we can edit a DB using it. Its called SQLite Client. Its available on the app store.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can include pre-populated **SQLite** file in your app.

**Steps to include sqlite**

1. Drag and drop the sqlite file(with the data) to the app bundle. Add the framework **libsqlite3.dylib**
2. Using **NSFileManager**, copy the file to documents directory to modify the sqlite data.
3. Then do your changes using sql queries.

Refer this link for more details->[Sqlite tutorial](https://www.raywenderlich.com/913/sqlite-tutorial-for-ios-making-our-app)